# Element-wise matrix operation returns zero (due to integer division)

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting a 3D surface in Python. Here muy1 and muy2 are two matrices created by meshgrid:

```
[[-5.   -4.75 -4.5  ...,  4.25  4.5   4.75]
 [-5.   -4.75 -4.5  ...,  4.25  4.5   4.75]
 [-5.   -4.75 -4.5  ...,  4.25  4.5   4.75]
 ..., 
 [-5.   -4.75 -4.5  ...,  4.25  4.5   4.75]
 [-5.   -4.75 -4.5  ...,  4.25  4.5   4.75]
 [-5.   -4.75 -4.5  ...,  4.25  4.5   4.75]]
```

After that a function Z is calculated and plotted

```
Z=zeros((40,40))
for xi in x:
    temp=1/2*(1-muy1)**2-1/2*(1-muy2)**2;
    print temp;
    Z=Z-temp;
print "Final"
print Z
```

However I keep getting Z to be 0. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`temp` is zero because it starts with `1/2`, which is integer division (resulting in zero).  Use `1./2` or `0.5` in both places to prevent that.

```
temp=1./2*(1-muy1)**2-1./2*(1-muy2)**2
```

Comment: or, `from __future__ import division`